# Texts from short code numbers to my iPhone do not play any notification sound or vibrate

Tags: iphone, ios, notifications

Many times, when I receive a text from a short code number (something like 12345), the text will show up in my notifications on the lock screen, but no notification sound will be played, nor will the phone vibrate.  Usually, this is an OTP from some website, but it can be from other services that require immediate response as well.  If I get a text or iMessage from a normal number, I get a sound or vibrate.  Other applications' notifications also sound/vibrate as normal.

Does anyone know why this is happening?  I'm currently on an iPhone 14 Pro running iOS 16.5.1, but this issue has been happening since at least iOS 14 on my previous iPhone 12.  It also occurs on a friend's iPhone 12 running 16.5.1.

Answer (score 0):

Open the settings app, select Messages, towards the bottom, make sure “filter unknown senders” is off.

Comment: It is off already.